# Get grand total from foreach looping laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

The `$grand_total` is always returning the last of `$row` value. Example : if the last row have subtotal **100000** , then grand total returning **100000** too.

```
@foreach ($cart as $row)
    @php
        $sub_total= $row->price * $row->qty;
        $grand_total = 0;
    @endphp
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li>Product Name : {{$row->product_name}}</li>
        <li><b>{{$row->price}}</b></li>
        <li>Qty : {{$row->qty}}</li><br>
        <li><b>Total : {{$sub_total}}</b></li>
    </ul>
    @php
        $grand_total += $sub_total;
    @endphp
@endforeach

<a href="/payment">
    <button style="width: 180px; height: 60px; font-size: 15px;">Checkout : Rp. {{$grand_total}} </button>
</a>
```

Or maybe I should have some change on my controller?

Comment: The real answer is to do logic in your controller. `$grand_total = $cart->map(fn ($row) => $row->price * $row->qty)->sum();`. Views are for viewing, not calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting `$grand_total` to 0 in each loop iteration. You should initialize `$grand_total` before the loop starts and then add `$sub_total` to each iteration.

```php
@php
    $grand_total = 0;
@endphp

@foreach ($cart as $row)
    @php
        $sub_total= $row->price * $row->qty;
        $grand_total += $sub_total;
    @endphp
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li>Product Name : {{$row->product_name}}</li>
        <li><b>{{$row->price}}</b></li>
        <li>Qty : {{$row->qty}}</li><br>
        <li><b>Total : {{$sub_total}}</b></li>
    </ul>
@endforeach

<a href="/payment">
    <button style="width: 180px; height: 60px; font-size: 15px;">Checkout : 
    Rp. {{$grand_total}} </button>
</a>
```

Comment: @Karl Please don't leave the important task of closing Off-topic: Typo questions to other contributors.  When you encounter a typo question, please use the privileges that the system has entrusted in you to spare this platform accumulating content that it doesn't want.

Answer (score 1):

because $grand_total is inside the for loop, take it out from the loop and you will be fine with the problem:

```
@php
$grand_total = 0;
@endphp
@foreach ($cart as $row)
    @php
        $sub_total= $row->price * $row->qty;
        
    @endphp
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li>Product Name : {{$row->product_name}}</li>
                <li><b>{{$row->price}}</b></li>
                <li>Qty : {{$row->qty}}</li><br>
                <li><b>Total : {{$sub_total}}</b></li>
            </ul>
    @php
        $grand_total += $sub_total;
    @endphp
    @endforeach

    <a href="/payment">
    <button style="width: 180px; height: 60px; font-size: 15px;">Checkout : 
    Rp. {{$grand_total}} </button>
    </a>
```

That should works.